# Rails - Render partial inside Twitter Bootstrap popover

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use a Twitter Bootstrap popover to display a user avatar and email address, with the possibility of adding in more details at a later date.

I am having an issue getting the partial to render inside the content field of the link. The view code is below (in HAML).

```
%span.comment-username
    =link_to comment.user_name, "#", "title" => comment.user_name,
      "data-content" => "=render 'users/name_popover'", 
      class: "comment-user-name"
```

Currently, this will only produce the content code as a string.

Is there a way to do this so the partial will be inserted instead of the code as a string?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want rails to actually evaluate the content of the string and not just show the string. The easiest way to do that would be:

```
%span.comment-username
  =link_to comment.user_name, "#", "title" => comment.user_name,
    "data-content" => "#{render 'users/name_popover'}", 
      class: "comment-user-name"
```

That should pass the render statement to rails and render your partial as expected.

Comment: Thanks - came to this conclusion after a bit of messing around. Hopefully helps some others.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get escaped HTML. Any suggestions?

Comment: @KyleDecot did u try :html => 'true' option?

Comment: @KyleDecot Sorry `html: true` was for js. In html you need to try `"data-html" => "true"`.

Comment: @anpsmn That works! Where is the documentation for this option just so I know where to look in the future

Comment: You can check [here](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers). Scroll down to 'Options'.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answer jrc - it helped me find a solution.

My solution might be useful for other non HAML people like me:

```
`<%= link_to('Service History' , '#', :class => "popover-history", :rel => "popover", :"data-placement" => "bottom", :title => "Service History", :"data-content" => "#{render 'services/service_history'}") %>`
```

with

```
`$(function () {
$('.popover-history').popover({ html : true });
});`
```

Comment: I wanted to display maps on a Rails 4.2.2 view. I wanted to use partials instead of straight html code just in case I wanted to change the formatting of the popover window. This solution answered my question.