# how to build a bootstrap popover in helper method for a view that will show a collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to create a view that will show a collection of objects rendered from a common partial template. This template will have a helper method that is supposed to return a html code that will show a link with a bootstrap popover containing a list of each object addition attributes. Going back to details, my helper method

```
def data_popover(status)
title = session[:switch] ? status.order.sim_rev : order_status.order.logo_code
content_for :details do
  content_tag :dl, class: 'dl-horizontal' do
    content_tag :dt, 'Client'
    content_tag :dd, status.order.logo.client
  end
end

return link_to title, order_path(status), :rel => :popover, :data => { 
          :delay => { show: 100, hide: 300 }, 
          :no_turbolink => true, 
          :trigger => "hover", 
          :placement => "top", 
          :html => true,
          :original_title => status.order.so,
          :content => content_for(:details)
        }
end
```

is not working as expected. I am having trouble with the `content_for :details` block, which is not rendering the correct HTML. What I get is

```
<a data-content="<dl class="dl-horizontal"><dd>NATIXIS PAIEMENTS</dd></dl>" data-delay="{&quot;show&quot;:100,&quot;hide&quot;:300}" data-html="true" data-no-turbolink="true" data-original-title="SO718424.009" data-placement="top" data-trigger="hover" href="/orders/26" rel="popover">V1089297/A</a>
```

Furthermore, each next object in collection is displayed as a sum of itself client name and all previous names. I have no idea why. Is it related to caching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting my question I noticed another [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444057/rails-render-partial-inside-twitter-bootstrap-popover?rq=1) that concerns similar problem. Following the solution from the latter I changed the helper method code to render a partial.

The partial code in ERB:

```
<dl>
  <dt>Client</dt>
  <dd><%= status.order.logo.client %></dd>
</dl>
```

and the code that calls the partial:

```
def data_popover(status)
  title = session[:switch] ? status.order.sim_rev : status.order.logo_code

  return link_to title, order_path(status), :rel => :popover, :data => { 
      :delay => { show: 100, hide: 300 }, 
      :no_turbolink => true, 
      :trigger => "hover", 
      :placement => "top", 
      :html => true,
      :original_title => status.order.so,
      :content => "#{render partial: "order_status_popover_details", object: status, as: 'status'}"
    }
end
```

With this approach I have no issues with progressive concatenation of client names.

Answer (score 0):

i had a customised buootstrap popover using js...try this:-
i have used popover to show user profile information..such as userimage,date of joining,favorites etc.Hope you can use this by modifying the html only instead of creating helper method,which i think is not a good option.

**html code===========**

```
   <div class="po-markup"> 

                 Posted on 
                  <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> <%= item.created_at.strftime("%b %d,%Y") %> 
                  by <i class="fa fa-user"> </i>
                 <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="po-link" ><%= user.username%></a>

              <div class="po-content hidden">
               <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-7">
                  <div class="po-title">      
             //show image/title/whatever you want
            </div> <!--/po-title -->
          </div><!--col ends -->
          <div class="col-lg-5">
                      <div class="po-body">
                      //show other details such as address/related categories etc    

              </div><!-- ./po-body -->
              </div>
            </div> <!-- ./row ends -->   
          </div>   
     </div><!-- po-markup ends -->
```

**js code to show customised popover....**

```
  $('.po-markup > .po-link').popover({
    trigger: 'hover',
    html: true,  // must have if HTML is contained in popover
    // get the title and conent
    title: function() {
      return $(this).parent().find('.po-title').html();
    },
    content: function() {
      return $(this).parent().find('.po-body').html();
    },
    container: 'body',
    placement: 'right'
  });//tooltip showing html content
```

Comment: @adass,,this is because this is something made to be done by js ,,,not by rails .